# Get Access to Embed tabBarController in App Delegate

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am facing a problem that I can get access to an embed tabbarcontroller and set it into index2

I have tried the following code but it won't work and it only goes to the first index:

```
UIStoryboard *secondStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainFunction" bundle:nil];
  MyViewController   *theInitialViewController = [secondStoryBoard instantiateInitialViewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = theInitialViewController;
    [self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];/        [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

[image]

It can't change to the second tab by using the above code.

Can anyone give me some advice?
Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewController getting from the story board is a tab bar controller.

```
  UIStoryboard *secondStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainFunction" bundle:nil];
  UITabBarViewController *theInitialViewController = [secondStoryBoard instantiateInitialViewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = theInitialViewController;
    [theInitialViewController setSelectedIndex:2];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```